# Getting data from associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 2 models that I am currently testing with. One is the top level model (Account::User) and the other is an associated model (Account::Profile). I am having some difficulty pulling data from the associated model.

The code below is for Rails 3.1

I am getting the exception:

`undefined method profile' for #<Class:0x7fe8aa0674b8>`

Currently my models look like this:

Account::User:

```
class Account::User < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_presence_of :username, :first_name, :last_name, :instance_id, :user_type, :is_active
validates_uniqueness_of :username

has_one :profile, :class_name=> 'Account::Profile'

def self.all_by_user_type(user_type)
  return all :conditions => ["user_type = ?", user_type]
end

def self.all_by_user_status(user_status)
  return all :conditions => ["is_active = ?", user_status]
end

def self.all_by_last_login(last_login)
  return all :conditions => ["last_login between ? and ?", last_login, Date.current]
end

def self.all_by_created_by(created_by)
  return all :conditions => ["created_by = ?", created_by]
end
end
```

Account::Profile

```
class Account::Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user, :class_name 'Account::User'
end
```

My controller action looks like this:

```
def dashboard
    @user = Account::User.profile
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `Account::User.profile`, you're trying to access a class method named `profile`. Now, `has_one` (and friends) actually sets up the relationship on instances of the class, so you might use it like `@user.profile`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you Sczizzo.

Answer (score 1):

`Account::User.profile` is not supposed to work. You could do something like this:

```
@user = Account::User.first
@profile = @user.profile
```